# glDrawArrays is failing with GL_INVALID_ENUM

Tags: opengl

I'm on OpenGL ES 3.0 using Mesa 17.0.3. When calling 
`glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4)`, 
`glGetError()` returns `GL_INVALID_ENUM`.

I have no idea what's causing it and https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml is claiming that GL_TRIANGLE_FAN is an accepted value for `mode`.

I'm checking for GL errors immediately before the call, and everything's fine then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `MESA_DEBUG=1` ([Debugging Tips | mesa3d.org](https://www.mesa3d.org/debugging.html), [Environment Variables | mesa3d.org](https://www.mesa3d.org/envvars.html)) and found out that `glEnable(TEXTURE_2D)` was causing the error.

I don't know why it only got triggered on the `glDrawArrays` (maybe weird bindings) but when I removed that call it no longer failed with `GL_INVALID_ENUM`.